# Group by in DB2

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query to fetch the nearest future doctor appointment for the users in DB2.

```
  SELECT user_id, 
         appointment_id, 
         date 
    FROM (SELECT user_id, 
                 appointment_id, 
                 date 
            FROM doctors_appointment 
           WHERE date > current_timestamp 
             AND user_id IN (23, 24, 25)
        ORDER BY date ASC ) as tmp_appointment 
GROUP BY user_id
```

But It throws error to include appointment_id and date in group by statement which means it asks to include all select fields in group by.

If I include all fields in group by the result will be like this:

```
   user_id    appointment_id      date 
   --------  ----------------     -------
    23            450             2011-07-20
    23            451             2011-07-26
    25            452             2011-07-18
```

But I need the result like below:

```
   user_id    appointment_id      date 
   --------   --------------       -------
    23            450             2011-07-20
    25            452             2011-07-18
```

Comment: Your acceptance rating needs to improve, and the `ORDER BY` is worthless in the derived table.

Comment: If you group  columns, the remaining columns need to be aggregate functions.

Comment: Do you need the minimum appointment ID for each user, or the earliest (minimum) date, or something else?

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result without using group by

Comment: yes.. earlist date and corresponding appointment id of that field

Comment: The most recent (as it says in your question) is not always the earliest (like you say in your comment). What do you need?

Comment: @cularis: The earliest or minimum date after the current date is the nearest future appointment.

Comment: I added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  This question is equivalent to that answered dozens of times on StackOverflow.  Just follow the tag as a link to see solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does the trick:

```
  SELECT D.User_ID, D.Appointment_ID, D.Date 
    FROM Doctors_Appointment AS D
    JOIN (SELECT User_ID, MIN(Date) AS Apt_Date
            FROM Doctors_Appointment 
           WHERE Date > current_timestamp 
             AND User_ID IN (23, 24, 25)
           GROUP BY User_ID) AS T 
      ON T.User_ID = D.User_ID AND T.Apt_Date = D.Date;
```

It would produce two rows for a given user if said user has two appointments on the same day.

Comment: I think you have your aliases `D` and `T`, reversed.